# How to loop over the same file using Filebeat

Tags: filebeat

I have some test data collected in a file that I would like to send continuously for testing purposes.

Is it possible to send the content of just 1 file over and over again using Filebeat (without doing anything manually while it's running)?

Comment: The answer is yes. There’s an answer and solution below

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. I've done this before and the way to get filebeat to ingest a file over and over again would be to have the Filebeat instance point to a specific directory. Then while Filebeat is running, copy and paste the desired log file to the directory that Filebeat is expecting logs from. That will have Filebeat notice and ingest the "new" file with the same data. Another option would be to write a script to copy that file to the expected directory every few minutes using a .sh script with something like a cp command.